# data-vocabulary.org schema

Tags: wp-admin

I am trying to solve this error but not getting the right way to solve so can you please help me to solve this error.

I am getting an error in Google's Structured Data Testing Tool and here's the error: **data-vocabulary.org schema is deprecated and not supported by Google anymore. Please migrate to using schema.org types.** I am getting this error for the Breadcrumb, you can find the screenshot below and my website is on WordPress.

Thank You in advance!

error's image

Comment: What are you using to generate the structured data - a plugin? Or is it built into your theme? Can you get an update to the plugin or theme that will now use the new schema.org types? You could try asking the developers if not. And if that fails, you'll have to find the code that generates this and fix it yourself, or maybe switch to something else that will generate the new format structured data.

Comment: @Rup

Everything is updated so that not might be an issue.
From where I can generate the code and where to change on WordPress?
Can you please help me with that?

Thank You!

Comment: You can either generate it in a plugin, in a wp_head hook, or in your theme's templates. Where to change depends on where the code is that is already generating the data-vocabulary.org version. Can you search your files, everything under the wp-content/plugins and wp-content/themes, for the string 'data-vocabulary.org' ?

Answer (score 1):

Most of themes usually come with a microdata markup which is implemented based on the vocabulary.org language...you might need to rewrite some JSON LD scripts which will be implemented in your functions.php file or you can as well use schema pro plugin for your structured data markup.

Specifically for breadcrumb, you may need to disable the default one that comes with your theme and implement a new breadcrumb structure using breadcrumb navxt plugin which has the correct schema markup based on the schema.org system.

This might require you to do some CSS stylings just to make the breadcrumb appear the way you want.

In all, the solution will depend on the wordpress theme you are using. You might also need a developer to help you write the schema or install the breadcrumb using Breadcrumb navxt which I have done previously. But if you are familiar with codes, you will be able to do this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to implement schemas:

- data-vocabulary
- microdata
- JSON-LD
- RDFa

As the error says, the data-vocabulary.org schema is deprecated. Currently, only the 3 other options are used. Google [encourages](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/intro-structured-data) people to switch to JSON-LD because it's more flexible and doesn't depends on the HTML markup, which sometimes is hard to change if you use a theme.

In the case of breadcrumbs, the same thing can be applied: you should switch to JSON-LD using a SEO plugin like [Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com) or [Slim SEO](https://wpslimseo.com). Both plugins offer shortcodes to display the breadcrumbs into your theme. And in case you don't use the shortcode, these plugins will still output the breadcrumbs in JSON-LD and that's compatible with the Google's suggestion.